# downvotes again; unfairly

Tags: discussion, down-votes

When I receive a down vote I question my maths and that's ok. What did I do wrong in this hint? It appears correct. [If $\sum |a_k|$ is convergent, is limit of $a_k=0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/616383/if-sum-a-k-is-convergent-is-limit-of-a-k-0/616390#616390)

It only gives me less confidence to answer when a user abhorrently trolls the site downvoting everywhere.

Comment: Even though the downvoter has not commented (yet), several suggestions have now been provided.

Comment: "It only gives me less confidence to answer when a user abhorrently trolls the site downvoting everywhere." You can't have that perspective and be a significant contributor here.  You cannot control who downvotes you sometimes - it is what it is.  Looking at your answer, I see what people are saying...really, you should really spend less time defending what you did and more time looking through the commenters' eyes.  And, well, forget about it: lots more math to do, so move on.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a specific answer which has since been deleted.

Comment: @Don please, if you feel inclined, have a look at my comment to Frank's question http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12196/should-people-write-many-equations-in-one-line

Comment: Due to this meta post, I took a look at your answer and I do not think that it is a good answer because it talks about a limit that does not exist, and you reply to this problem that the result is true in that case, anyway. This is not a mathematically sound reply. So, I am not surprised at all that someone down-voted it. Talking about "trolling" is way out of line.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you asked...

I took a look at your post, and it is at best unclear.  Labelled as a "hint", you suggest "add an infinite amount of the limit" to prove the proposition.

And that's all you wrote.

There are a number of community members who will post hints as answers, but when challenged the typical response is to add more detail to the post until a complete answer emerges.

You've responded by complaining about unfairness.  If you can give a coherent proof, it would serve future readers to fill in what can easily be argued is a gap in your present answer.

I'll provide more specifics as Comments to your Answer, but if you have improvements to make to the Answer, it would be timely to do so in view of the downvotes.